# Etymology of Ancient Greek deictic -ī

Tags: etymology, indo-european, greek

In Ancient Greek, a deictic particle -ī can be attached to demonstratives to strengthen the "this here" meaning: e.g. houtos "this one", houtosī "this one right here". What is the origin of this -ī?

Indo-European has the so-called "hic et nunc *i*", which appears in the present verb endings and in other places, but this *i* is short while the Greek *ī* is long, so equating the two isn't straightforward.

Comment: Have a look at what Beekes says s.v. –ι.

Comment: @fdb I don't have Beekes handy, would you mind summarizing?

Comment: @ TKR  verbatim: -ī [pcl.] particle added to pronouns, mostly of demonstrative value. <IE *-iH 'demonstrative pcl.>
• VAR Att. ὁδ-ί, οὑτοσ-ί, νυν-ί, etc.; also El. το-ΐ, Boeot. ταν-ί TUV-I, etc., rarely -ίν.
•ETYM Comparable with the enclitics Skt. OAv. lm, 1, and -i in Hitt. asi, uni-, ini­ 'that (one),; perhaps-also seen in Lat. uti. Gothic has a deictic element -ei.